# dataset function is used before been assigned a value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am trying to correct some of the warnings a ASP.NET application is throwing. I see many warnings of the type

```
"Warning    1   Variable 'ListPostFrom' is used before it has been assigned 
a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."
```

From functions like:

```
    Public Function ListPostFrom(Optional ByVal SortCol As String = "dept", Optional ByVal SortOrder As String = "ASC", _
                            Optional ByVal ActiveOnly As Boolean = False) As DataSet

    Try
        Dim objDepartmentDA As New DepartmentDA

        'Fill dataset
        ListPostFrom = objDepartmentDA.ListPostFrom(SortCol, SortOrder, ActiveOnly)

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Dataset may be empty
        Return ListPostFrom    << This is the line with the error

    End Try

    'Return dataset
    Return ListPostFrom

End Function
```

My question is, what is the best way to correct these type of warnings?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably handle the exception, since it's inside the `catch` block.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, that fixed my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This way you have a dataset that is Nothing(assigned value) so if it does not fill then it returns Nothing so just check for that before using. Since a function returns something you need to make sure it has a value.

```
Public Function ListPostFrom(Optional ByVal SortCol As String = "dept", Optional ByVal SortOrder As String = "ASC", _
                        Optional ByVal ActiveOnly As Boolean = False) As DataSet
 Dim result As DataSet = Nothing
 Try
    Dim objDepartmentDA As New DepartmentDA
    'Fill dataset
    result = objDepartmentDA.ListPostFrom(SortCol, SortOrder, ActiveOnly)
 Catch ex As Exception
    'do nothing  
 End Try
 Return result 'may be nothing
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim ds = ListPostFrom()
If Not ds Is Nothing Then
   'use ds in here
End If
```